# Getting sum of the data from yesterday's

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding getting yesterday's data in oracle sql
my query is something like this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) 
FROM 
   FABRICATION_HIST 
WHERE 
   FAB_ENTRY_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

The value in `FAB_ENTRY_DATE` is like this:

**8/25/2014 3:03:11 PM**

And it doesn't show any data when I execute the query, Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More efficient (if FAB_ENTRY_DATE has index - uses it):

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) 
FROM FABRICATION_HIST 
WHERE FAB_ENTRY_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
  AND FAB_ENTRY_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

**NOTE:**

Don't use `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` to drop time part:
as it works only if default date format on database is 'MM/DD/YYYY', if not - you get errors like this:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month : SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) 
FROM 
  FABRICATION_HIST 
WHERE 
  to_date(FAB_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

[You should match only the date part]

or

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) 
FROM 
  FABRICATION_HIST 
WHERE
  FAB_ENTRY_DATE >= (SYSDATE - 1) and FAB_ENTRY_DATE < SYSDATE;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147   I think that you should avoid between as as the url states `expr2 <= expr1 AND expr1 <= expr3`, so your second example would include rows that `FAB_ENTRY_DATE` is equal to `SYSDATE`.  I would advise either use the first case mentioned here or explicitly `>= AND <`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I assumed that it would be `<` instead of `<=` on the higher side.

Comment: I think it is a common mistake. I use between a lot too. It would be very rare to have an entry exactly on the turn of the day anyway...:-)

Answer (score 1):

You have equality. `8/25/2014 3:03:11 PM` won't be equal to `8/25/2014`
You need to specify a range:

```
WHERE FAB_ENTRY_DATE >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
      AND FAB_ENTRY_DATE < TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can trunc data column:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) 
FROM 
   FABRICATION_HIST 
WHERE 
   to_date(FAB_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = trunc(SYSDATE) - 1
```

see [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) 
FROM 
   FABRICATION_HIST 
WHERE 
   TO_CHAR(FAB_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Since you don't need to get the `sum` on a span of dates (between two dates), you can compare the date that you want as varchar without the *Time* portion. `"8/25/2014" = "8/25/2014"`